# Is there a way to display timestamp in unix format to ISODate?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We stored a date using unix timestamp in MongoDB, how do I get the date when I do the query?  Is there a way to display timestamp in ISODate format?

Comment: Where are you trying to display the ISODate .. in the `mongo` shell, or are you using a particular language driver?

Answer (score 16):

#### Background

- A [unixtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unixtime) value represents *seconds* since the epoch (Jan 1, 1970).
- A [JavaScript Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)  represents *milliseconds* since the epoch.
- In MongoDB, [`ISODate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#date) is a convenience wrapper for `Date()` that allows you to create dates from ISO strings in the `mongo` shell.  If you use `new Date()` in the shell, it will return an `ISODate()`.

#### Conversion

To convert between a `unixtime` and an ISODate() you can multiply your unix timestamps by 1000 and pass this value to the `new Date()` constructor.

#### A simple example in the `mongo` shell:

```
> db.mydata.insert({
    unixtime: 1362143511
})

> var doc = db.mydata.findOne();

// convert unixtime seconds to milliseconds and create JS date
> var date = new Date(doc.unixtime * 1000);

> date
ISODate("2013-03-01T13:11:51Z")
```

Comment: I think the example should say new Date and not new ISODate.

Comment: @Pukku Thanks! Corrected the example :)

Answer (score 9):

Mongodb 4.0 has introduced [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) aggregation, so you can try with it

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "toDate": {
      "$toDate": "$unixTimestamp"
    }
  }}
])
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6-RYH1VqZ09)

Answer (score 6):

In the Mongo console you can create a JavaScript `Date` object from a timestamp before the document is printed to the screen:

```
> db.stuff.find().forEach(function (doc) {
  doc["timestamp_field"] = new Date(doc["timestamp_field"])
  printjson(doc)
})
```

Be careful with that code, unlike a regular `find()` it will not page the results but print every matching document without pausing.

Comment: need to multiply by 1000 as Stennie has mentioned below.